# Getting data out of PlainObject in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I love JQuery-style argument parsing and want to use it in my own function:

```
   foo( { 'name': 'bob', 'age': 21 });
   function foo (param){
     alert($.isEmptyObject(param)); //shows true

     //now what?  :-)

     //param.prop('name'); does not work
     //$param=$(param); $param.prop('name'); still does not work
     //treating it as an array also does not work
   }
```

How can I get at the data I passed?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You're currently calling a function named `param` and passing an object to it, but you haven't shown us the code for your function `param`. You also have not shown us how `foo` is being called, which is of course vital for what the value of `param` will be within `foo`.

Comment: Did you mean `foo( { 'name': 'bob', 'age': 21 });`?

Comment: Eh, yes, I did mean foo.  Sorry for the typo.  I corrected the post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are exactly doing, but this works just fine:

```
foo( { 'name': 'bob', 'age': 21 });

function foo (param){
  alert($.isEmptyObject(param)); //shows false
  alert(param.name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you're doing on the first line. It looks like you're calling a function named `param`, but if that's the case, you're not assigning the returned value to anything.

It looks like you want to pass an object into `foo`, in which case perhaps what you intended was this:

```
var paramObject = { name: 'bob', age: 21 }; //JS object to pass into foo
foo(paramObject); //Call foo, passing in paramObject
function foo(param) {
    console.log(param.name); //Prints "bob"
}
```

If I've misunderstood, and you do actually have a function named `param` that returns an object, it might be useful to post the code of that too.

Comment: Thanks! this worked great. I don't know why I wasn't able to find the param.name syntax.  Silly of me.  :-)  (And the post had a typo.  Your assumption about my intent was correct!)